# Reserve day in cricket

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

The recently concluded fourth test in Ashes between England and Australia ended in a draw where England were looking to draw the series , but unfortunately rain spoiled the game which ended in draw.So my question is can the match officials enforce a reserve day (rain interrupted matches) in test cricket on the request of Captain rather than holding reserve days only for ICC events like WTC final?
Also the second test match between India and WestIndies ended in draw again due to rain.Where India would have won the match if in case there was a reserve day.So is reserve day only used in ICC events like WTC final , ICC cricket world cup,ICC T20 worldcups only ?

Comment: The first half of this question ("why cant ICC enforce a reserve day?") is honestly too opinion-based for this site. The second half ("is reserve day only used in ICC events?") is a good question though - would you be happy to edit this to remove the first half?

Comment: Hi @PhilipKendall, is the question edited ok now? I feel its good to refer match officials as they represent ICC in international matches.

Comment: Seems fine to me - "can they do X" is answerable.

Comment: My agenda or the key note is that why only ICC events get privileges like reserve days.Whereas normal series matches between countries wont have any of such advantages.You might tell ICC events are played for a trophy and are accredited globally,whereas these matches is just meant between two cricket playing nations.

Comment: FYI there are some points added for WTC qualifications also right for test matches , these dent the qualification scenarios for any nation just because rain affected their score (win points) even though draw also gives points to teams , but when win is so close , rain god has spoiled the win points to both England and India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say for argument sake that adding an extra day at the end of a test is easy to organise and available to the teams...

What circumstances are you going to get where both teams agree to play an extra day? In the case of the Ashes, with play abandoned, Australia retained the Ashes. Pat Cummins is never going to agree to a reserve day and risk that. The match officials are literally there to be the people who do not care who wins or loses. Australia not wanting to play will carry just as much weight as England wanting to play.

The ICCs motivation for having reserve days for their finals is to maximise the chances that they can hand a trophy over to a team after the final has been played. They dont have the same worries or stakes with a series between two nations.

Comment: An obvious way to decide whether to have the extra day would be if less than 5 * 90 (the minimum required per day) overs have been bowled.

Comment: Do you mean 4*90? If its less than that then you know you have lost a day.

Comment: Depends what you think the goal is. Maybe you do another full day if it's less than 360, maybe you do a "partial day" if it's less than 450. In any case, it's an objective measure which nobody gets a choice in whether it happens or not.

Comment: At which point you may have less than 24hrs to organise a day of cricket. A stadium would almost certainly have to guarantee that a sixth day could happen before the match started but you wouldnt be able to sell tickets for it. Suddenly you're seeing your costs go up by up to 20% while being unable to guarantee any income.

Comment: They manage it for the WTC Final, which in some ways is _harder_ to sell tickets for because it (at least until now) has never involved the "home" team.

Comment: And out of all the test matches that happen every two years its also the only one with a reserve day so you could quite easily say 'They can _only_ manage it for the WTC Final'. Rain has been a thorn in crickets side ever since the first ever new ball was taken and every so often it will throw a complete spanner in the works and the total lack of reserve days tells me that everyone has made their peace with that possible outcome.